# how to get custom camera view in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to make an app which will take snap from camera.the view of the camera would be within a particular area say it would be in a user specified area.is it possible to show the camera controls in another view which will be attached with the camera view as the camera view would be pretty small to show all the camera controls.